# How to send authorization code from 1 API to another API using Regular Expression Extractor in Jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter, authorization, extractor

```
I have an API name loginUser, which generates the authorization Token, that is to be passed in other subsequent APIs.

    Below is the response:-

    HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Sat, 10 Nov 2018 07:08:45 GMT 
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
    Content-Length: 71 Connection: 
    keep-alive Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu) 
    X-Powered-By: Express Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * Access-Control-Expose-Headers: date, authorization, x-powered-by, connection, server, access-control-allow-origin, content-type, content-length, x-final-url 

    authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiIyYmEyYjc1My03NWEwLTQxNGYtYWFiOC0zZGY1M2I4YmIwMDEiLCJpc0Nvb2siOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTU0MTgzMzcyNX0.3FRVpHm4EF2Ahzzy-OjbZ2EeZto6-hSFKHNtG5wcjBs

    Where I want to fetch the authorization.

    I'm using Regular Expression Extractor, but it is throwing below error
```

org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: URI does not specify a valid host name: http:/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiI4MWFiNzI3NS01MWU2LTQyMTctYmJlNC03ZTJlYjk1Y2M1NGYiLCJpc0Nvb2siOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTU0MTk5NDY0NX0.kI0VrNARu09iG589g80ruqNFkoUQDg2iI9sw2nOuasU
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.determineTarget(CloseableHttpClient.java:95)

```
    Snapshots:-

    [Step_1][1]
    [Step_2][2]
    [Step_3][3]
    [Step_4][4]


      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2aC8.png
      [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/plORl.png
      [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xe6aY.png
      [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQMjZ.png
```

Please let me know, what can be done to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. Can you please paste the image of the request corresponding to the erroneous HTTP Auth Token sampler?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is not related to the Regular Expression Extractor at all, it is about some [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler having incorrect hostname

As far as I can see you can successfully extract the header value, but you should not be using it as the hostname, most probably it should go:

- as one of the request parameters (i.e. directly in body or as a part of the URL)
- as a [HTTP Cookie](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)
- as a [HTTP Header](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

So you need to find out how the token should be passed and provide the variable from the regular expression extractor there, but it is obviously not "Server Name or IP" field of the HTTP Request sampler.

---

Be aware of existence of the alternative way of recording a JMeter test which automatically detects handles dynamic parameters so you will not have to worry about extracting and substituting dynamic values. Check out [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) article for more details

Comment: I solved it, by using Bean Shell Pre-Processor, Thanks :)